# Rails ajax insert additional form fields into form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am trying to add a new select fields to my form through the built in rails ajax methods but not really sure how to proceed. I've looked at other ajax rails SO but if there is a more relevant one that somebody has found that offers direction, that would be helpful.

details.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @event, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
# lots of forms here

    <div id="add-field">

    </div>
    <%= link_to "Add Event Detail", add_event_detail_path, remote: true %>

    <%= f.submit "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

events/build_controller
added this

```
def add_event_detail
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

add_event_detail.erb

```
$("#add-field").append("<%= f.select(:event_detail, options_for_select([['Option1', 'Option1']) %> <%= f.text_field :event_detail %> ");
```

I also added this route for now

```
match "/add_event_detail" => "events/build#add_event_detail", via: 'get'
```

I have a few issues (besides the bad code that you might see). How do you pass the `f` variable into the jquery append method and what would be a good way to deal with unique name's for each newly created form essentially, `:event_detail1` `:event_detail2` etc. Ideally I would want to link that name to the selection in the form

e.g. :location for the option :location

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to look at nested_form gem i.e.(https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields), it can dynamically add fields to a form.
or try to look at RailsCasts #403 Dynamic Forms it will give u a clear direction.
Hope this helps u to the right direction.

Comment: I haven't, but this seems solvable without a gem. I'm just not sure what next.